# Is placing imports on the bottom of React component legal?

Tags: reactjs

In React, by default, in almost any source code I've seen, the imports are placed on top of the file where a component is located. In case of many imports (which is a code smell by the way, I know it) when we open any component we need to scroll down, often a lot.

I believe that first thing we want to see when we open a component is the render method.

Is it bad idea to put imports on the bottom of the file? It seems to work, but does it have any negative consequences?

Answer (score 1):

The major of the linter not only will warn you if imports are not on the top of your code, but also will warn you if absolute import comes after relative imports.

**It works, but make your code by far less readable.**

Answer (score 0):

It is a general practice to write all the imports at the top.

If somebody else will work on your code and wants to look for imports, he will look for them at the top and it will be confusing not to find them at the top.